# i'm getting an error (502 bad gateway) when i run a function on my online server. i don't get the same error when running on my local server

Tags: python, flask

the main goal of what i want to do is to update my mongodb database with data from a json (it's a magic the gathering cards database i'm working with). when running locally, it works fine. when running online, it doesn't work and i get this 502 error

this is the javascript function that i'm calling via a button

```
$(function() {    $('.test').live('click', 'button', function()
{

name = $(this).prev().val();
console.log(name);
    (
    $.ajax({
    url: "/test",
    data: {"name":name},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {

    $('.divteste').empty();
    $('.divteste').append(response);

    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log('err');
        console.log(error);
        $('.divteste').append(error);
    }
})

)})});
```

this is the corresponding python route

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])  # 
def test():
    pos=[]
    string=reescreve()
    return '..'
```

this is the main thing that's supposed to be executed

```
def processa(name,lista,layout): # checks whether the card is already exists in the database. if it does, updates it with further information if necessary.
temp=[]
temp2=[]
temp.append(lista)


num=CARDS_COLLECTION.find({"functionalname":name.lower()}).count()  ### checks if MTG card already exists in my database
if num==0:
    CARDS_COLLECTION.insert({"functionalname":name.lower(),"name":name, "layout":layout, "address":temp})


elif num>0:   ###  if it does, it might be necessary to add another set, i.e., another edition in which that card was printed to the document.
    temp3=[]
    query=CARDS_COLLECTION.find({"functionalname":name.lower()})
    for k in query:
        for j in k['address']:
            temp3.append(j[0])
    if lista[0] not in temp3:
        CARDS_COLLECTION.update({"functionalname":name.lower()},{'$addToSet': {'address': lista } })
return ('',204)



def reescreve():


CARDS_COLLECTION=MongoClient()['lista']['Cards']

CARDS_COLLECTION.remove()

content = json.loads(open("cards.json").read())

    for j in content:
        try:
            print j['name']
            if j['layout']=='normal' and j['digital']==False and j['set_type']!='memorabilia':
                url=str(j['image_uris']['normal'])
                final=url[url.find('normal')+6:]
                final=final[0:final.find("?")]
                processa(j['name'],[j['set'],j['set_name'],final],j['layout'])
        except:
            return 'fail2'
return ('',204)
```

ps: i never get this 'done' printed on my page when running online, whereas when running locally, yes

Comment: Please use actual code instead of using images. There is a [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) available.

Comment: What host and port you use to startup Flask in both situation?